# Is (VBA VBScript Regex Method) returns an array?

Tags: regex, vba

**I have little experience with regular expression and I am still learning it.**

In the below code, I have to use a number after `rg.Execute(str)` otherwise it dose not work.
so, Is (VBA VBScript Regex Method) returns an array?
and what I need to do If I want to return all matches?

```
Function Extracts(str) As String

    Dim rg As Object
    Set rg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    
    rg.Pattern = "\s?[0-9]+"
     rg.Global = True
      rg.IgnoreCase = True
      
    Extracts = rg.Execute(str)(0)
    
End Function
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  RegExp.Execute returns a `MatchCollection` object that includes all of the matches.  You're just throwing them all away except the first.  It's a normal VBA Collection that has a `Count` method to tell you how many there are.